# Haskell - Parameter count that fit criteria?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Let's say I have a function:

```
isOne :: Int -> Int -> Int
isOne x y =
```

Then if `x == 1` and `y != 1` then it returns `1` (one of the parameters equals 1), if `x == 1` and `y == 1` it returns `2` (because both are 1), if `x != 1` and `y != 1` it returns `0` etc.

I can't figure out how to do more than a single check with an if statement (or using cases).

Comment: `isOne a b = let f 1=1; f _=0 in f a + f b`

Comment: `isOne a b = length . filter (==1) $ [a,b]` generalizes quite handily to more arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to this is with pattern matches.  You can define a function by cases, which are interpreted in the order at which they occur

```
isOne 1 1 = 2
isOne 1 _ = 1
isOne _ 1 = 1
isOne _ _ = 0
```

alternatively, you can use guards

```
isOne x y | (x == 1) && (y == 1) = 2
          | (x == 1) && (y != 1) = 1
          | (x != 1) && (y == 1) = 1
          | otherwise            = 0
```

again, these are checked from top to bottom.  That is, if the first guard matches then it goes with the first equation, otherwise it tries the second, and so on.  This can also be written

```
isOne x y | (x == 1) && (y == 1) = 2
isOne x y | (x == 1) && (y != 1) = 1
isOne x y | (x != 1) && (y == 1) = 1
isOne x y | otherwise            = 0
```

or

```
isOne x y | (x == 1) && (y == 1) = 2
isOne x y | (x == 1) || (y == 1) = 1
isOne x y | otherwise            = 0
```

another way of doing it would be to use an `if then else` expression.

```
isOne x y = if (x == 1) && (y == 1) 
            then 2 
            else if (x == 1) || (y == 1) then 1 else 0
```

or perhaps you could try doing

```
isOne x y = (go x) + (go y) where
   go 1 = 1
   go _ = 0
```

or any of dozens of other ways...

Comment: @Ingo Yep.  I would have been first if I hadn't edited the question.  :)

Comment: What if I need to count values that are ABOVE another value. For instance, find out how many parameters are above '4' for instance?

Also it's not just 2 parameters, let's say it's 3?

Answer (score 6):

Why, you just need to translate your english to Haskell:

```
if (x==1) && (y /= 1) then 1
else if (x/=1) && (y==1) then 1
...
```

But you really want:

```
isOne 1 1 = 2
isOne 1 _ = 1
isOne _ 1 = 1
isOne _ _ = 0
```

or, even shorter:

```
isOne x y = fromEnum (x==1) + fromEnum (y==1)
```

Comment: lol "Why, you just need to translate your english to Haskell."  Isn't that always true?

Answer (score 4):

### Method 1

Use paired `case` statements

```
isOne x y = case (x, y) of 
  (1, 1) -> 2
  (1, _) -> 1
  (0, 0) -> 0
  ...
```

### Method 2

Use nested `if` statements

```
isOne x y = if x == 1 then (if y == 1 then 2 else 1) else 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd second using either direct pattern matching in the function definition, or `case` on tuples.

But the most readable alternative would IMO be `length [ q | q<-[x,y], q==1 ]`.